# Fieldset elements not in line

Tags: html, css

how can I modify this fieldset to make its element in line as in the following image?

[image]

```css
/*
MFN0634, Lab 04 (NerdLuv)
You should link to this provided stylesheet from all of your pages.
You should not need to modify this file.  Your pages should work with it as-is.
*/

* {
 font-size: 12pt;
 font-family: "Verdana", "Geneva", sans-serif;
}

a {
 color: #F44;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 background-color: #FFA;
}

a img {
 border: none;
}

#bannerarea {
 margin-bottom: 2em;
}

body {
 background-color: white;
 padding-left: 1em;
}

body > div, form {
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 35em;
}

div {
 overflow: hidden;
}

/* form styles */
fieldset {
 background-color: #E0E0FF;
 border: 2px outset gray;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

/* the bold text labels to the left of each form field */
fieldset strong,
ul strong,
fieldset label.left,
fieldset .column {
 float: left;
 width: 11em;
}

h1 {
 margin-top: 0em;
}

input[type="submit"] {
 background-color: #FAA;
 font-size: 120%;
 font-weight: bold;
}

legend {
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px outset gray;
 padding: 0.2em;
}

.match {
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.match img {
 width: 150px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.match p {
 background-color: #E0E0FF;
 clear: left;
}

.match ul {
 padding-left: 160px;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding-left: 0em;
}

ul li a img {
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#w3c {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
<form action="signup-submit.php" method="post" name="datiUtenti">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>New User Signup:</legend>
    <div class="column">
    <b>Name:</b><br>
    <b>Gender:</b><br>
    <b>Personality type:</b><br>
    <b>Favorite OS:</b><br>
    <b>Seeking age:</b><br>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
    <input type="text" name="name"/></br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked> Female</br>
    <input type="text" name="eta" maxlength="2" size="6" /></br>
    <input type="text" name="pt" maxlength="4" size="6" 
    placeholder="ENTJ" />
    <a href="http://www.humanmetrics.com/cgi-win/JTypes2.asp">
 (Don't know your type?)</a></br>
 <select name="sistema">
      <option value="linux" selected="selected">Linux</option>
      <option value="windows">Windows</option>
      <option value="macosx">Mac OS X</option>
    </select></br>
    <input type="text" name="seek1" maxlength="2" size="6" placeholder="20" /> to
    <input type="text" name="seek2" maxlength="2" size="6" placeholder="45" /></br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

I cannot modify the css file. I tried to separate it in two columns, but it didn't worked. If I use the  tag for the left part it will be bigger than the right part, so this is why I used .

Comment: Can you modify the HTML, and provide *inline* CSS? There's no way you're going to be able to do this otherwise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<body>
    <form action="signup-submit.php" method="post" name="datiUtenti">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>New User Signup:</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Name:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Gender:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked>Female</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <b>Personality type:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="eta" maxlength="2" size="6" />
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="pt" maxlength="4" size="6" placeholder="ENTJ" />
                        <a href="http://www.humanmetrics.com/cgi-win/JTypes2.asp">
 (Don't know your type?)</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Favorite OS:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="sistema">
                            <option value="linux" selected="selected">Linux</option>
                            <option value="windows">Windows</option>
                            <option value="macosx">Mac OS X</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Seeking age:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="seek1" maxlength="2" size="6" placeholder="20" /> to
                        <input type="text" name="seek2" maxlength="2" size="6" placeholder="45" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't use `<table>` for layout. An answer with just a code sample is a bad one. Explain why this work and what you did.

Comment: I would start right now, with this answer, or you may just get more downvoted.